# How to pass text input to a php function?

Tags: php

I have the following code on a php page:

```
<form action="" method="get">
First Name:
<input type="text" name="first"/><br />
Last Name:
<input type="text" name="last"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

It is a form to add a new user to a sqlite database. In another file I have this php function:

```
function addUser($firstName, $lastName) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS
            (FIRST, LAST)
            VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName')";
    return execSQL($sql);
}
```

So what I want to do is pass the text that a user enters in the text fields to the function (which has been placed in the global scope, but is in a different document). How can I do this?

Comment: i dont see where the problem is .. just call the addUser function after you get ur values from the $_GET .. and dont forget to do some validation and filtration

Comment: fill up the "action" part of the form, submit, and then retrieve the values you passed in php using $_GET array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You FORM method is get so use $_GET.As you mentioned in action your php code and form should be in same page.

```
<?php

$firstname=''; // Declare your variables first 
$lastname='';  // Declare your variables first 

if(isset($_GET['first']) && isset($_GET['last'])){ // Then validate it
$firstname = $_GET['first'];  
$lastname = $_GET['last'];
 addUser($firstName, $lastName); // Then use your function call
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to load a new page which calls this function using the variables from the form and then displays a confirmation message. You can get these variables with $_GET['variable name'].

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have used `get` method in your form, so you need to use `$_GET`.

```
if(isset($_GET['first']) && isset($_GET['last'])){
   $firstName = $_GET['first'];
   $lastName = $_GET['last'];
   addUser($firstName, $lastName); // passing the value into function
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the form action to a page which includes:

```
addUser($_GET['first'], $_GET['last']);
```

**However, this code is vulnerable to SQL injections and should never be used in production.** Make sure you at least run it through mysql_escape_string, or preferably switch to PDO and use parameter binding.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php